# Add validation on multiple single checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, eloqua

I have group of single checkbox for topic of the event. I want the checkbox to be required. The code will be used in Eloqua so HTML code can't be change, as well the onsubmit function.

```
<div id="formElement1"><input name="singleCheckbox" type="checkbox"><label style="margin-left: 4px">Topic 1</label></div>
<div id="formElement2"><input name="singleCheckbox2" type="checkbox"><label style="margin-left: 4px">Topic 2</label></div>
<div id="formElement3"><input name="singleCheckbox3" type="checkbox"><label style="margin-left: 4px">Topic 3</label></div>
<div id="formElement4"><input name="singleCheckbox4" type="checkbox"><label style="margin-left: 4px">Topic 4</label></div>
<div id="formElement5"><input name="singleCheckbox5" type="checkbox"><label style="margin-left: 4px">Topic 5</label></div>
```

Comment: from what i can see your checkboxes are all disabled

Comment: To require a form element you simply have to add attribute 'required' to it. But, if you can't change HTML... :-( Do you want to implement it in javascript?

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, I want to use javascript.

Comment: What is a multiple single checkbox ? There is 5 single checkbox here. Is it some <select><option> you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have access to jQuery, this is the simple code to add the 'required' attribute to formElement1' element:

```
$('#formElement1').attr('required', true);
```

Otherwise, with bare javascript:

```
document.getElementsById("formElement1").setAttribute("required", true);
```

Comment: I dont want to add required property on all checkbox, I want the validation on the whole group.

Comment: Which is the group id? In your code, it is not shown... However, you can use the group id, instead of the id of one checkbox, it will work as you expect...

Comment: It's not really a group checkbox. But multiple single checkbox.